# Ionic 2 E2E Testing with protractor

Tags: e2e-testing, ionic2

Struggling to get my head around E2E testing on my Ionic 2 app. I've read that I should use protractor but I don't know how to do this with Ionic 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Protractor is straightforward to set up with Ionic 2. Briefly, you need:

- an e2e test file
- a config file for protractor
- a gulp (or similar) job to build your e2e if you've written it in Typescript
- to install protractor

I've written a [walkthrough for Ionic 2](http://lathonez.github.io/2017/ionic-2-e2e-testing/) with full source code available on [github](https://github.com/lathonez/clicker)

EDIT: as of Ionic 2 RC1 we've updated the project and associated walkthrough to use ng-cli.

Comment: first link is broken